# How to get from Flores to Sulawesi?

Tags: air-travel, transportation, indonesia, sea-travel

I want to get to Sulawesi (Makassar I suppose) from Flores.

Is there any direct flight or ferry?

Or must I go first to another location (i.e. Bali) to take a flight from there?

Any budget option appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to prove a negative, especially in a country like Indonesia where airlines pop up and disappear overnight, but **no**, I don't believe there are any direct flights or ferries.

There are three airports of any size on Flores: [Komodo/Labuanbajo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komodo_Airport) (LBJ), [Ende](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._Hasan_Aroeboesman_Airport) (ENE), and [Maumere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frans_Seda_Airport) (MOF), none of which serve Sulawesi's largest city and geographically closest airport in [Makassar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sultan_Hasanuddin_International_Airport) (UPG).  It's thus highly unlikely that there are any direct services, and you're probably best off detouring via [Denpasar-Bali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ngurah_Rai_International_Airport) (DPS), which is well connected to all four and a bunch of other airports in Sulawesi as well:

[image]

(courtesy [Great Circle Mapper](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=LBJ-DPS-UPG;LBJ-UPG))

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the Indonesian travel website http://www.tiket.com?  It looks like you can fly on Wings from Maumere to Makassar for about $175 (stops in Denpasar).

http://en.tiket.com/pesawat/cari?d=MOF&a=UPG&date=2015-09-17&adult=1&child=0&infant=0

[image: Flight Maumere to Makassar via Bali]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a direct flight from Flores to Makassar. I don't know where in Flores will you start your journey, but [here](http://edyraguapo.blogspot.de/2014/02/bandara-bandara-di-provinsi-nusa.html) is a list of airports (bandara) in East Nusa Tenggara, of which 4 are in Flores. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sultan_Hasanuddin_International_Airport#Airlines_and_destinations) is the international airport in Makassar. There is a table showing which airline flies to which city.

You could look for possible connections in websites such as Skyscanner or Kayak, but I think not all options are shown there. I usually use a local website, [Traveloka](http://www.traveloka.com/), or direct in the airline's website. My favorites are [Garuda Indonesia](https://www.garuda-indonesia.com/id/id/index.page) and [Citilink](https://book.citilink.co.id/) (LCC, a subsidiary of Garuda).

PS: Just noticed that this question is already 3 months old. I hope you've already figured it out.